# iOS/SpriteKit - getScale from node

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

is there possibility to get scale value from node?

because xcode warning me with "No getter method for read from property".

Thanks
PSS

Answer (score 1):

Use `node.xScale` and `node.yScale`.